# Can Xcode 4.1 and 4.2 beta 4 be installed safely side by side on the same (Lion) machine?

Tags: xcode4

Are there any issues when installing xcode 4.1 and 4.2 beta 4 side by side on the same mac (10.7)?

Comment: off topic how? see faq. "software tools commonly used by programmers". I'd say xcode qualifies.

Answer (score 4):

No, no issues. Of course, you will need to install them in separate locations.
To make it work, I needed to uninstall 4.2 first, then install 4.1, and finally install 4.2 again, in a different folder.

They both work fine, and can be run side by side as well.

Comment: From both, so they were updated for 4.2 -- I am mainly using 4.2, so I haven't done extensive testing of the tools.
Let us know if you run into any problems, so others will know about them, too. To me they seem to work well.